# Destroy session on click close btn(X) in tab

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```js
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function(){


     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page/out.php"
     });
    
}
</script>
```

I am trying to destroy session if user pressed (X) in tab

I used the `onbeforeunload` event but the session is destroyed each time when I click the "Submit" button in the form or just refreshing the page

Comment: Use something like a session cookie, or sessionStorage, it will be deleted once the browser is closed.

Comment: sessions deleted once the browser is closed  it's working bro , but i mean on close current tab in browser not the browser itself , knew what i mean ! ? :D ,  sorry my english is too bad

Comment: @MohamedHasan You can restore the session with session cookies or sessionStorage ...

Comment: Almost sounds to me like you should try to avoid creating a session in the first place and go with something like a url-based cookie or some XSRF shit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep a **flag** to check whether you clicked on a Submit `button` or Close `button` of `browser`.

```
<script>
var btnClickedFlag = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function(){

  if(!btnClickedFlag){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "page/out.php"
    });
  }    
}

$('button').click(function(){
  btnClickedFlag = true;
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: How to detect if the close button of the browser was clicked?

Comment: @Teemu.. Op's question is related to "Submit button" page reloads as the form gets submits. So, whatever code OP provided will work for close button of the browser.

Comment: Yes, and in general, any redirecting, including refreshing too, which all should keep the session. Your answer works with form submission only.

Comment: yea it's good idea when submit my form works fine but when close tab no sessions delete, maybe i should use session cookies or storage  like Endless and Teemu said .